# Passing variables from template to view

Tags: django, templates, view

Ok, I'm working on a website and I need a way to save score to database. I get the score from an iFrame, but I dont know how to pass it to a Django view to save it to the DB.
This is the template I'm using to get the score:

```
{% block content %}
<script>
  /* global $ */
  $(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(window).on('message', function(evt) {
      //Note that messages from all origins are accepted
      //Get data from sent message
      var msg = evt.originalEvent.data;
      if(msg.messageType == "SCORE")
      {
        msg.score
        ???
      }
    });
  });
</script> 
<iframe id="game_iframe" src={{gameurl}}></iframe>
{% endblock %}
```

I will be using some sort of model to save the score eventually but now I'm just interested passing this variable from the template to the view.

Comment: This isn't really a Django templates question, it's more of a JS question I suspect. One possible answer is to launch an Ajax POST request that calls a Django view. But maybe you could say a little more about what you've tried and which part is causing you difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is setup an Ajax request & handle the score etc in a django view.

Take a read of this & it should give you everything you need; http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html

You'll probably end up with JS a bit like this;

```
{% block content %}
<script>
  /* global $ */
  $(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(window).on('message', function(evt) {
      //Note that messages from all origins are accepted
      //Get data from sent message
      var msg = evt.originalEvent.data;
      if(msg.messageType == "SCORE")
      {
        $.get('/game/save_score/', {score: msg.score}, function(data){
           $('#score').html(data);
       });
      }
    });
  });
</script> 
<iframe id="game_iframe" src={{gameurl}}></iframe>
{% endblock %}
```

And a view;

```
def save_score(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    score = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        score = request.GET['score']

    # Do whatever you need to save the score.

    return HttpResponse(score)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried adding url(r'^/game/score/$,save_score) in urls.py as mentioned in the link you gave, but I get 404 from that.Then I tried url(r'^/game/score/(?<score>\d+(?:\.\d+))/$', save_score) that gave 500. I tried adding alert to the response function to see if it works but it has never popped up yet.$.get('/games/score/', {score: msg.score}, function(data){
           //$('#score').html(data);
     alert("woho");
       });

Comment: Ok I had an unneccessary / in the url mapping, but I still get error 500 when trying to submit score. "GET /game/save_score/?score=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 10255

Comment: @OuTsei can you update your question with the view, the URL pattern & the traceback from the 500 please?

Comment: @OuTsei ha, it's always the simple stuff that we overlook!